# using package glossary and hyperref for acronyms: Only link from abbreviation?

Tags: hyperref, glossaries, acronyms

I'm using

```
\definecolor{citeC}{rgb}{0.00,0.32,0}
\definecolor{refC}{rgb}{0,0,0.75}
\usepackage[pdftex,colorlinks=true,urlcolor=refC,linkcolor=refC,citecolor=citeC]{hyperref}
\usepackage[acronym,nonumberlist]{glossaries}
```

for my acronyms. When I define an example acronym i.e.

```
\newacronym{UBL}{UBL}{Urban Boundary Layer}
```

and then use it for the first time

```
\gls{UBL}
```

this will create a hyperlink like

[image]

which links from the whole word "Urban Boundary Layer" and from the acronym "(UBL)". Is there any possibility to only link from the acronym itself? Like:

[image]

I want my links to be colored but I dont want the whole word to be colored. So I thought the best way  would be to remove the hyperref from the first part of the acronym? How can I do that?

Answer (score 4):

The simplest method is to use the [`glossaries-extra`](https://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries-extra) extension package. If the `nohyperfirst` attribute is set, this will switch off the hyperlink on first use. The `long-postshort-user` abbreviation style can then be used with the short part put in a hyperlink (`\glsxtruserparen` is only used on first use to put the short part in parentheses). Subsequent use behaves as normal.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{refC}{rgb}{0,0,0.75}

\usepackage[colorlinks,linkcolor=refC]{hyperref}
\usepackage[acronym,nonumberlist]{glossaries-extra}

\makeglossaries

\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long-postshort-user}

\glssetcategoryattribute{acronym}{nohyperfirst}{true}

\renewcommand*{\glsxtruserparen}[2]{%
  \glsxtrfullsep{#2}% space between long part and parenthetical material
  (\glshyperlink[#1]{#2})%
}

\newacronym{UBL}{UBL}{Urban Boundary Layer}

\begin{document}
First: \gls{UBL}.

Next: \gls{UBL}.

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

[image: image of document]

(If you get an undefined abbreviation style or undefined control sequence error, then you need to update your version of `glossaries-extra`.)